# Why does my Eclipse load with phantom breakpoints and old errors?

Tags: java, eclipse

So, I deleted a breakpoint after using it a LONG time ago. Everything I load Eclipse, they are back. It's very wierd, some never reappear, and some reappear daily for months and months, until they disappear. I also sometimes load into old compile errors, many of which are completely irrelevant to their line, or not even on a line(in whitespace), and cleaning the project is mandatory each load.

I'm running Linux if it matters, but I recall this happening on my Windows too. I do copy my preferences from machine to machine.

Comment: You try with another workspace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by `waypoint` you mean `breakpoint`, try to just clear *all* breakpoints:

In Eclipse, open the `Breakpoints` view. If not already visible, show it by selecting pull-down menu "Window" > "Show View" > "Breakpoints".

Click the double-X in the view toolbar. Hover shows "Remove All Breakpoints".

Close Eclipse to ensure the new setting is *saved*. If Eclipse (or your OS) crashes, changes to settings like that are lost.

Comment: Yes, sorry, have been thinking a lot about AI this morning.

Comment: Need to apply some of that AI to yourself, especially the "I" part. ;-) --- We could all use a bit more of that.

Comment: That did clear the breakpoints. I didn't see phantom errors this time, but I don't always see them. I'll open a new question for them if I see them again so I can be more specific. Thanks!